# Changing Registry Value

Tags: vba, registry

I'm trying to use VBA to create a .vbs script which changes a registry value in the Windows Registry Editor. I'm trying to change the **(Default)** value which is a **REG_EXPAND_SZ** in the Key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command`

The code to change is currently:

```
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000

strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "txtfile\shell\open\command"
strValueName = ""
strValue = "Test Value"

objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
```

The problem is that it doesn't work when I use the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key. I've tested this exact code when changing a value in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. What I think is that there needs to be security or permissions added to the script in order to change a value it the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key.

What do I have to do to make this work?